# Xcode 4.5 different iPhone backgroud on iPhone 4s and 5

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5, screen-resolution, iphone-4, iphone-5

I have made two different background images for my iPhone app: one in 640x960px (iPhone4s) and one in 640x1136px (iPhone5). But when I create the application layouts in the Xcode 4.5 Main Storyboard, how do I define and create it for both iPhone4s and iPhone5? So that the background automatically updates when i choose iPhone5 screen?

Comment: want to change the splash screen?

Answer (score 1):

Just import your background image with the correct suffix

For example :

`myImage.png` for non-retina display

`myImage@2x.png` for retina display

`myImage-568h@2x.png` for iPhone 5

Answer (score 0):

In your viewController set:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"]];
```

Remember to correctly named the image:

- for iphone4 "image@2x.png"
- for iphone5 "image-568h@2x.png"

Comment: Isn't it possible to do this in Interface Builder, without using code?