# Xcode 4.5 background image iPhone 4, 4s, 5

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, screen, iphone-5

I have in my viewController.m written the background code:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

And I have the correct names of the different pictures:

```
image.png for non-retina display (320x480)

image@2x.png for retina display (640x960)

image-568h@2x.png for iPhone 5 (640x1136)
```

But when I run it in the simulator it does not take the image-568h@2x.png for iPhone 5 screen it only takes the image@2x for 4s screen and scale it to fit the screen... I dont know if there is any coding to use the image-568h@2x for iPhone 5 screen?

Im using Xcode 4.5

Comment: which version of Xcoe you are using?

Comment: Original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055007/xcode-4-5-different-iphone-backgroud-on-iphone-4s-and-5 Instead of recreating the questions, consider providing more information in the original one, gaining a little reputation and starting a bounty.

Comment: version 4.5, what does it mean to starting a bounty?

Comment: it means offer more points to someone who answer this question... if you offer 50 bounty that will be added to someone whome you accept ansewr and debited from you account...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

iPhone 5 is retina, just like iPhone 4 and 4S, and the @2x-image will be used automatically for all these devices. It's only the startup-image that is called "-568h@2x" for iPhone 5. You need to write some code to use a different image, something like this would work:

```
NSString *filename = @"image.png";
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
if (screenRect.size.height == 568.0f)
    filename = [filename stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".png" withString:@"-568h.png"];

imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:filename];
```

Comment: is the "imageView" here @synthesize? or..?

Comment: Check out this sample-project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gcc081dy0frs20z/RetinaImageTest.zip. If you run it in the different simulator devices, you will see three different (extremely ugly) images :) They should of course be different resolutions, but it's a proof of concept.

Answer (score 3):

if you are trying to use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]` and expect `image-568h@2x.png` to be picked automatically from the bundle for iPhone 5, it will not work. 
Automatic picking works only for iPhone 4 and 4S.

Only the Default image named as `Default-568h@2x.png` will be picked automatically in iPhone 5.

for normal images, if you have separate image for iPhone 5, try using this code

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
    // code for 4-inch screen
} else {
    // code for 3.5-inch screen
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is incorrect to assume that you can apply the `-568h@2x` trick to *all* image files. I think it *only* works for `Default-568h@2x.png`. This is the file that iOS looks for at app launch on a 4" display device, as well as the "flag" to enable 4" display support in the SDK. For example, once you include this specific file, your table views will fill the screen.

I have not read anything to suggest that you can simply provide any image with the `-568h@2x` file name component and have it be used automagically. You'll have to do that yourself based on the screen size, e.g. `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height`.