# Displaying different images for iPhone 4 & 5

Tags: ios, uiimageview, iphone-5

This seems to be an interesting problem that I'm getting. I'm developing an iPhone app for iOS 6+ devices and optimizing the images for both iPhone 4 & 5. Now I have implemented this into my project: [Xcode 4.5 background image iPhone 4, 4s, 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070369/xcode-4-5-background-image-iphone-4-4s-5)

The problem is in interface builder I'm designing the UI with the iPhone 5 screen, so the UIImageView is 320x568. But when I test on iPhone 4, the image is being stretched and looks terrible. However, the specified image for the iPhone 4 screen is displaying, i just want its dimensions to be 320x480

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the inspector view in the interface builder, you can edit the stretching behavior of the view when the size of the super view changes. You can click the red arrows inside the square to control that.

[image]

Also I suggest that you check `UIView contentMode`. You can edit that from the inspector view in the interface builder "third tab from the right.

Answer (score 0):

In the UIImageView's inspector, try playing with the Mode property. The Aspect Fill or Aspect Fit may get what you're looking for to handle the different screen sizes.