# Xcode: Background image resized in app

Tags: iphone, xcode, background, resize

I'm using a 640x1136 image as background for my app but the image appears zoomed in. The same image, as splash screen, is displayed correctly. I followed the directions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070369/xcode-4-5-background-image-iphone-4-4s-5).
Two pics,

the original image:

[image: 640x1136 image]

Screen capture, simulator iPhone 6.1, and the look is the same on my iPhone 5

[image: screen capture]

The code I am using is the following:

```
CGRect screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
if (screenSize.size.height == 568.0f) {
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-568h@2x"]];
}else {
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default@2x"]];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tabbar at bottom of application. So, you need to use different image for Splash screen and background screen for Inicio tab.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ratina images(Having suffix as @2x) and checking in NonRetina simulator. So select Retina based simulator using iphone simulator property as

```
Hardware -> Device -> iPhone(Retina 4-inch)
```

and then run app.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: @user2339310: Well, I have cut 49 pixels from the image with the same results. Nishant Tyagi:I'm running the app on an iPhone 5, the zoom in effect is both on the simulator and on the iPhone.